# Node JS canvas image data

Tags: node.js, canvas

I am trying to read a image and the result i want to get is the same when you use a HTML canvas "Uint8ClampedArray"? `var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, height);` I found a NPM lib [canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas) but i cant get it to install.

So is there a another way to go without using Canvas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To strictly answer the question:

> So is there a another way to go without using Canvas?

The issue is that, even if we can load an image binary data, we need to be able to parse its binary format to represent it as raw pixel data (`ImageData`/`Uint8Array` objects).

This is why the [canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) module needs to be compiled when installed: it rely on and links to [libpng](https://libpng.sourceforge.io/), [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/) and other native libraries.

To load a `Uint8Array` representing pixel raw data from a file, without canvas (or native library wrapper), will requires decoders running only in Javascript.

For e.g. there exist decoders for png and jpeg as third-party libraries.

### Decoding PNG

Using [png.js](https://github.com/devongovett/png.js/):

```
const PNG = require('png-js');
PNG.decode('./image.png', function(pixels) {
   // Pixels is a 1d array (in rgba order) of decoded pixel data
});
```

### Decoding JPEG

Using [inkjet](https://github.com/gchudnov/inkjet):

```
const inkjet = require('inkjet');
inkjet.decode(fs.readFileSync('./image.jpg'), function(err, decoded) {
  // decoded: { width: number, height: number, data: Uint8Array }
});
```

https://github.com/gchudnov/inkjet

Answer (score 4):

Do not realy know what i did to get canvas to work. I used pixel-util to set image data.

```
var pixelUtil = require('pixel-util'),
    Canvas = require('canvas');

var image = new Canvas.Image,

pixelUtil.createBuffer('http://127.0.0.1:8080/image/test.jpg').then(function(buffer){
    image.src = buffer;

    canvas = new Canvas(image.width, image.height);

    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
    runImage(ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height));
});
```

Comment: i got canvas is not a constructor