# How to use Tensorflow.js with node.js in this instance?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow

The example
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/coco-ssd

loads the image from the browser like so:

```
(async () => {
  const img = document.getElementById('img');

  // Load the model.
  const model = await cocoSsd.load();

  // Classify the image.
  const predictions = await model.detect(img);

  console.log('Predictions: ');
  console.log(predictions);
})();
```

Although this works in the browser, I'd like to make it work in pure node.js. Is there a way without creating a dom object (such as canvas), loading the data using the fs module?

Comment: aside: its not clear to me. does model.detect work on a `img`. In other words what is the expected input to `model.detect`?

Comment: @tyskr Does it really matter if the `object` passed to it has the properties it needs formatted correctly in pure `javascript`? I'd print out the entire `img` object which works and check which object members are needed for that library to work with it. Setting aside anything else that library might need related to regular `DOM`.

Comment: Then you could just create a wrapper/constructor which generates those objects which has same properties in node.js. For example `img` element has `src` attribute which is in that context `img.src`. Pretty sure you need only that for it to work with maybe some metadata of the image.

Comment: @zendevil, You need a library to convert an img to a format this library can consume. Much like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47487831/1971378.  These are the formats this library takes: https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/coco-ssd#detecting-the-objects

Comment: The library uses tensorflowjs APIs [ts.browser.fromPixels](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/1.0.0/#browser.fromPixels) if non-tensor type is provided. So there are options. You can convert the image into a tensor like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758368/convert-base64-image-to-tensor) post and use that instead.

Comment: @user3647971 passing a map where "data" is the data param in the fs callback {data: data, height: 200, width: 200} into model.detect is accepted, but I'm getting no predictions with the cat.jpg stock image in the demo

Comment: @zendevil The nodejs fs module documentation in first page has 138 references to word "data" so I'm not quite sure what kind of data that is. The model.detect seems to just typecheck the input parameters then call infer method which converts non-tensor data to tensors and tries to build predictions with those. The parameter passed to model.detect _has_ to be of type ImageData or HtmlImageElement or Tensor3D(can be casted from Tensor) otherwise it just fails without notice as far as I can see.

Comment: @user3647971 tf.node.decodeImage worked with new Uint8Array()